# How to check if currently logged in user exists in Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

We have a web application where LDAP/Active Directory authentication is in place.

Now the requirement is if user, which exists in Active Directory, is logged in to his machine and accesses the web application, then it doesn't require authentication. It will directly authenticated and landed to website's landing page.

Could you please guide if you have any idea/hint/ref/solution?

Thank you so much.

Comment: For example we have two users A and B. Consider A is exists in AD and B is unknown user. If A logged in then it will automatically get validated. In case of B, it will ask for credentials and give an error.

Comment: It won't be a same machine from where A and B logged in.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to change the authentication to "Windows" , this will force your website users to enter their windows credential and then you can validate those on page load

1) Enable Windows authentication in IIS and disable Anonymous authentication for more information see this article : [Windows Authenticaition for ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages)

2) On Page load identify the identity of user using `Page.User.Identity`

3) Query LDAP through `using System.DirectoryServices` and `using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` to check if user exist or not

For more detailed info on AD this is a very useful article [Almost Everything about AD](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C%27#12)

Answer (score 1):

With respect to above answer by Bhavin.

Also set
Internet Options--> Security --> Custom --> 
User Authentication --> Automatic logon only in intranetzone

This is browser specific setting can be done via group policy also.